# get value from a filtered array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array of objects each object contains a name property and a value property

[image]

what I want to do is return the value for the specified name

I am using a computed property

```
computed: {
    statAlertCount() {
      var stat = this.siteStatistics.filter(item => {
        console.log(item);
        return item.name == "site_alert_count";
      });
      console.log(stat[0]);
    }
  }
```

this code returns and object 'stat' which i can console out. it looks like this.

[image]

but if I try to access the value using stat[0].stat then I get the following error

```
app.js?id=f37d3d495892e39c6054:85474 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'stat' of undefined"
```

Comment: @ksav comes back with undefined

Comment: `statAlertCount()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I hadn't got that far,  all these issues are with in the functiion

Comment: it says 'error in render' so the problem is when this function is called during render it isn't returning anything

Comment: @JaChNo how are you accessing `stat` or `statAlertCount` in render?

Comment: If you are getting the error from render you have gotten far enough to need a return — you're trying to use the value created by `filter` but your computed value returns `undefined`.

Comment: I have updated it to return, which was an ommision, but it still returns the object and not the value

Comment: I've updated my answer...

Comment: well I think its time for a [mcve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just need to return:

```
computed: {
  statAlertCount() {
    var stat = this.siteStatistics.filter(item => item.name === "site_alert_count");

    return stat.length > 0 ? stat[0].stat : '';
  }
}
```

Comment: seems correct, I'd use `return this.siteStatistics.find(` since it seems the first elem is wanted anyway

Comment: yes but then I am returned an object like this "name": "site_alert_count", "stat": "3" } I want it to return the value

Comment: Just do `return stat[0].stat;`

Comment: this is the same problem. admittedly I had forgotten the return but I get the same error Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'stat' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using `find`:

```
computed: {
  statAlertCount() {
    const statItem = this.siteStatistics.find(item => item.name == "site_alert_count");
    return statItem ? statItem.stat : "";
  }
}
```